# Check Proof on Rudin's PMA 2.16

Tags: real-analysis

I mainly want someone to check my solution and guide me in the right direction if needed. Apologies if this was already answered somewhere else, but I did not want to look at anybody's solution. I've been tackling these problems on and off, and to be perfectly honest, I just want to move on to a different problem.

Problem: Regard $\mathbb{Q}$ as a metric space, with $d(p,q)=|p-q|$. Let $E$ be the set of all $p\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $2<p^2<3$. Show that $E$ is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{Q}$, but that $E$ is not compact. Is $E$ open in $Q$?

**$E$ is bounded**, just consider $-2022$ and $2022$.

**To show $E$ is closed**, I will show $\mathbb{Q}\cap E^c$ is open, so that for arbitrary $x\in \mathbb{Q}\cap E^c$, $x$ is an interior point of the complement. Need to find $r$ such that $B_r(x)\subset E^c$. After some computation, take $r=\min \left \{\sqrt{2}-|x|,|x|-\sqrt{3}\right \}$.

From here, for $y\in B_r(x)$, we would have two cases to show that $y\in E^c$. Note that $y\in B_r(x)$ implies that $y\in (x-r,x+r)$, so $y<x+r$ and thus $|y-x|<|r|=r$.

*Case one:* $r=\sqrt{2}-|x|$, so $|y|<|y-x|+|x|<r+|x|=\sqrt{2}$.

*Case two:* $r=|x|-\sqrt{3}$, so $|y|=|x-(x-y)|\geq ||x|-|x-y||=|x|-|x-y|>|x|-r=\sqrt{3}$. Note that $||x|-|x-y||=|x|-|x-y|$ for $y>0$, but a similar argument can be made if $y<0$.

In either case, either $y^2<2$ or $y^2>3$, so $y\in E^c$. Since $E^c$ is open, $E$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$.

**To show E is not compact**, consider the open cover $A_n:=\left \{\mathbb{Q}\cap \left [-\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{2}-\dfrac{1}{3n}\right ]\right \}\cup {\left \{\mathbb{Q}\cap \left [\sqrt{2}+\dfrac{1}{3n}, \sqrt{3}\right ]\right \}}$. This is an open cover of $E$ with no finite subcover, so E is not compact.

I had trouble **showing $E$ was open**, but I honestly think I was burnt out by this point. I think I want to show each $x\in E$ is an interior point. To show a neighbourhood $B_r(x)\subset E$, I want to show there exists $r$ such that $2<x^2<3$ implies that $2<(x+r)^2<3$. I am having a total blank, I know it is some simple arithmetic calculation. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can do very similar argument as showing $E^c$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be simpler to prove the results for $E_1 = \mathbb{Q}\cap(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, then state that it's similar for $E_2 = \mathbb{Q}\cap (-\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{2})$, and finally conclude that the results hold for $E = E_1\cup E_2$.

To show that $E_1$ is closed, we need to show that any limit point $p\in\mathbb{Q}$ of $E_1$ is in $E_1$. Assume $p\neq E_1$ then either $p<\sqrt{2}$ or $p>\sqrt{3}$ (because $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ are irrational so there's no equality). If $p<\sqrt{2}$ then there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $p+\epsilon < \sqrt{2}$; clearly there is no point of $E_1$ in the segment $(p-\epsilon, p+\epsilon)$ and thus $p$ is not a limit point, contradiction. Similarly for the case $p>\sqrt{3}$. We conclude $p\in E_1$ and thus $E_1$ is closed.

To show that $E_1$ is open, let $p\in E_1$, i.e., $p$ rational and $p>\sqrt{2}$ and $p<\sqrt{3}$. Then there exists $\epsilon$ such that $\sqrt{2} + \epsilon < p < \sqrt{3} - \epsilon$, which means that $\mathbb{Q}\cap(p-\epsilon,p+\epsilon)$ is entirely in $E_1$, thus $E_1$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

Use $$E = \{p \in \mathbb{Q} : \sqrt{2} < |p| < \sqrt{3}\},$$
$$E^c = \{p \in \mathbb{Q} : |p| \leq \sqrt{2} \text{ or } |p| \geq \sqrt{3}\} =  \{p \in \mathbb{Q} : |p| < \sqrt{2} \text{ or } |p| > \sqrt{3}\}$$
since $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3} \notin \mathbb{Q}$. From continuity of $f(x) = |x|$ it is clear that $E$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$ and $E^c$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Apologies, but this chapter of Rudin is only on definitions and topology. Continuity and real-valued functions are later in the book.

Comment: @Alex You can prove these are open directly using $||x| - |y|| \leq |x - y|$ (this is just how you prove continuity of $|\cdot|$, thats why I said continuity.)